# Why is there no airport beacon light symbol on the sectional for KSAC, although it does have one?

Tags: airport, usa, aeronautical-charts, airport-lighting

The star symbol on the top of the airport means airport beacon light but
Sacramento Executive (KSAC) has no star symbol but they do have a beacon light and controlled airport as well.

Is that misprinted or any reason for that?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I believe it's because the beacon doesn't operate continuously.

The FAA [Aeronautical Chart Users' Guide](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/aero_guide/media/editions/22Apr2021/cug-complete.pdf) says:

> The symbol [...] indicates the existence of a rotating or flashing
> airport beacon operating from dusk to dawn.

However, KSAC's beacon doesn't operate from dusk to dawn; pilots have to activate it using CTAF, in the same way they can activate pilot controlled lighting. The [Chart Supplement](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/dafd/) for KSAC says:

> When twr clsd ACTIVATE arpt bcn—CTAF

I assume that because the beacon isn't operating continuously, showing it on the chart would be misleading to pilots who aren't aware of the Chart Supplement information. If you look at the airport diagram for KSAC, you can see it uses a different symbol from the standard one for the beacon.